# html table increase height of a text inside td

Tags: html, css

- Is it possible to increase `font-size` of a `<td>` content vertically only?
- I want to increase the only height of texts which are inside `<table>` `<td>`'s

Comment: can you be more specific ? maybe looking for line-height

Comment: Are you referring to `font-size` which only effect inside the `<td>`.?

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 transform has the scale function for it.
The following code is a working example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        td {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 65px;
      transform: scale(.5, 1);
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <td>aaaaaa</td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: transform scale is working but td content is going outside of column vertically

Comment: you can apply padding to the td cells

Answer (score -2):

You can make it td a hover effect by adding this line

```
td:hover{
        font-size: 100px;
    }
```

Comment: OP Didn't ask about making it have a hover effect, so why is this an answer?